# How to repeat string message without use asterisk, loop, array, import

Tags: python

I get a quiz about programming python.
**Input:** 3 lines of any string. (only 3 lines)
**Output:** 3 * 5 = 15 lines of string which repeat 3 lines of input 5 rounds
** But this quiz has restricted word: `import` `for` `while` `*` `.` `sep` `if` `else` `elif` `list` `set` `tuple` `dict` `[]` `{}` `lambda` `map` `filter`

I already try it by use asterisk character to repeat string but this is restricted word. It cannot submit.

```py
STRING_A = input()
STRING_B = input()
STRING_C = input()
STRING_RESULT = STRING_A + "\n" + STRING_B + "\n" + STRING_C + "\n"
print(STRING_RESULT * 5)
```

## Example

**Input:**

```
man
in
middle
```

**Output:**

```
man
in
middle
man
in
middle
man
in
middle
man
in
middle
man
in
middle
```

Thanks for your helping.

Comment: Are you certain such a solution exists? With these restrictions, the only option I can see is having 5 `print(STRING_RESULT)` statements.

Comment: @TheGamer007: I think it exists. Please check my answer below. Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56454244/how-to-repeat-string-message-without-use-asterisk-loop-array-import/56455175#56455175.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good fit for StackOverflow. This is asking for help for a programming puzzle, not asking for programming help or advice. Also: if the person asking you this question is doing it to test your competency: RUN. It's unlikely that they're qualified to judge your abilities if they think that _this_ is any indicator of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your restrictions, **recursion** sounds like a good approach. Give this a shot!

```
def repeater(a,n):
    n <= 0 and exit(0)
    n == 1 and print(a)

    print(a)
    return(repeater(a,n-1))

STRING_A = input()
STRING_B = input()
STRING_C = input()

STRING_RESULT = STRING_A + "\n" + STRING_B + "\n" + STRING_C
repeater(STRING_RESULT, 5)
```

Output:

```
man
in
middle
man
in
middle
man
in
middle
man
in
middle
man
in
middle
```

Comment: Good attempt, but the restricted words also include `if` `else` and `elif`.